# jquery on click sibling selection

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I generate a Table from a database to look like this

```
<table id="items">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Goldmine ID</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="evenrow">This is a test Description generated through UNIT Tests for the category description</td>
        <td class="evenrow"><input type="text" value="" id="106" class="gminput"></td>
        <td class="butCell evenrow"><button class="saveButton updateitem">Update</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="oddrow">This is a test Description generated through UNIT Tests for the category description</td>
        <td class="oddrow"><input type="text" value="" id="107" class="gminput"></td>
        <td class="butCell oddrow"><button class="saveButton updateitem">Update</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="evenrow">This is a test Description generated through UNIT Tests for the category description</td>
        <td class="evenrow"><input type="text" value="" id="108" class="gminput"></td>
        <td class="butCell oddrow"><button class="saveButton updateitem">Update</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the input box value and id returned by the relevant row's button click

so far I have tried this but failed

```
$('body').on('click', '.updateitem', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(index) {
        alert(($(this).val()));
    });
    var par = sib.parent('td');
    par.addClass('redBorder');
});
```

Comment: I could summarize your question into one sentence ;)

Comment: As a side note, it's `.each`.

Comment: @user1534664 Personally I've read the whole and I like to have enough information to be sure of what is required. The HTML was especially useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element you want is

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.gminput')
```

You can get the value and id using

```
var input = $(this).closest('tr').find('.gminput');
var value = input.val();
var id = input.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `forEach()` in jQuery.. try `.each()`

```
$(this).parent().parent().each(function(index) {
   if(!$(this).hasClass('butCell')) {
       if($(this).find('input').length > 0) { // we have to verify if tds has text inputs or not
           alert($(this).find('input').val());
       } else {
           // if there is no text input we get the text inside td
           alert($(this).text());
       }
   }  
});
```

Comment: yes I get this I am writing quickly and usually work in C# forgive my mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.updateitem').on('click', function(){
    $elem = $(this).parents('tr').find('.gminput');
    var id = $elem.prop('id');
    var val = $elem.val()
})
```

Why have a click event on `body`, when `button` might suffice?

Comment: I guess the `<tr>`s are dynamically generated.

Comment: Still suffers from the issue in case the rows are dynamically generated.